# jenkins test results to Zephyr

Tags: jenkins, junit

i have some Junit tests that i run each push to git via Jenkins
i would like to report those test results to Zephyr for Jira.

i am doing it using the Jenkins pipeline, this is my pipeline code:

```
node{
    stage 'connect to git'
        ....

    stage 'run test'
        sh 'ant test'

    stage 'report test result'
       step ([class: 'JunitResultArchiver' , testResults="reports/Test-*.xml"])
    step ([class: 'ZfjReporter', serverAdress:'....', projectKey:'....', versionKey:'1', cycleKey:'createNewCycle', cycleDuration:'1 days', cyclePrefix=''])
}
```

when running the last stage i get the next error: 'no known implementation of interface jenkins.tasks.simpleBuildStep is named ZfjReporter'

can you please help me. i could not fina an answer to this issue.

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you have found the comment on [this jira issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32801):

"I add compatibility with Pipeline plugin, now you can run a step of Zephyr fro jita test management plugin"

The commenter, Ivan Fernandez Calvo, also linked to [this pull request](https://github.com/jenkinsci/zephyr-for-jira-test-management-plugin/pull/2), where he implemented the changes. Unfortunately, that pull request, though filed in 2016, was never merged (as of 20 Aug 2017).

So I think you're out of luck in terms of using this plugin in a Jenkinsfile at this point. Sorry. :(

Comment: Ohh, I see. Thank you.